# jdbctemplate concept and c#

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net, jdbctemplate

Is there something similar with spring jdbctemplate for c# ?

I am not seeking for jdbctemplate for c# but something that works very similar like jdbctemplate.

I am familiar with ado net and linq to entities, but I like the concept of jdbctemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have `ADOTemplate` in Spring.NET:

http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/ado.html#ado-adotemplate-intro

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Java guy, but I took a look at the jdbctemplate to see what it is and see if I could think of anything similar in .NET.

I may be off, but to me that looks somewhat similar to the [Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.data.database_members(PandP.31).aspx) class in the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data Application block.  It's not an exact match, but something similar in concept in that it is meant to abstract database access and make it a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

[Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) is the most similar to Spring JdbcTemplate and very very easy to use. No context, no tracking, just mapping results to objects.
It is created by StackOverflow developers and also maybe the most popular ORM (technically micro ORM) after EF. If you have a Pluralsight account there is a [course](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/getting-started-dapper/) about it presented by a Microsoft employee, else there is plentiful of videos on Youtube as well.